# Как при клике на кнопку вывести данные, относящиеся только к ней?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

Я не уверен в правильности моего кода.

Есть JSON-файл, в котором хранится расписание учителя:

```
{"teachers":[
{"name":"Пачгина Алевтина Афанасьевна",
"timetable":[{
    "para":[{
        "t":"1-2",
        "l":"Ф",
        "g":"15",
        "k":"320"}]}
]},
{"name":"Арсентьева Татьяна Ивановна",
"timetable":[{
    "para":[{
        "t":"3-4",
        "l":"Б",
        "g":"12",
        "k":"222"}]}
  ]}
]}
```

И HTML-файл:

```
<div ng-controller="teacherController">
    <button ng-click="loadNT()">ТЫК</button>
    <br>
    <div ng-show="loadedNT" id="div1">
        <br>
        <input type="text" ng-model="search">
        <div ng-repeat="teacher in teachers | filter:search">
        <hr align="left" width="250" size="2" color="#ff0000" />
        <button ng-click="loadL(id)">{{teacher.name}}</button>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="loadedL">
            <div ng-repeat="teacher in teachers">
                <div ng-repeat="timetable in teacher.timetable">
                    <div ng-repeat="para in timetable.para">
                        {{para.t}},{{para.l}},{{para.g}},{{para.k}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/teacherController.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
teacherApp.controller('teacherController',
function teacherController($scope, $http){

    $scope.loadedNT=false;
    $scope.loadedL=false;

      $scope.loadNT = function (){
        $http({method: 'GET', url: 'teacher.json'}).
            then(function success(response) {
                $scope.teachers=response.data.teachers;
                if ($scope.loadedNT==true) {
                    $scope.loadedNT=false;
                }
                else {
                    $scope.loadedNT=true;
                }
        });
    };

    $scope.loadL = function (id){
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'teacher.json'}).
        then(function success(response) {



            if ($scope.loadedL==true) {
                    $scope.loadedL=false;
                }

            else {
                $scope.loadedL=true;
            }

        });
   };

}
```

Как вывести *timetable* только одного учителя?

Comment: не совсем понял вопрос, но если речь идет о том что бы пользователь мог посмотреть подробную информацию об учителе, то почему бы не передавать в этот метод как параметр `teacher`. а лучше перепишите вопрос так что бы было понятно что Вы хотите сделать

Comment: В моем коде, при выводе расписания учителя, выбрасывался абсолютно весь json, то есть при клике на одного учителя выводилось его расписание и расписание других, это проблему я решил простым добавлением `id` каждому учителю и передаче этого `id` при клике на учителя `ng-click="loadL(teacher.id)"`, и передавал его в контроллер `$scope.timetable=$scope.teachers[id].timetable;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас уже есть все данные, не нужно их каждый раз загружать.
Сделайте по ним фильтрацию

1. В функции loadL() задайте *name* учителя для фильтрации(я не увидел id), а во втором цикле по учителям отфильтруйте по этому значению так же как вы это делали в поиске выше. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter
2. Уберите *ng-show="loadedL"*. Данные уже загружены

HTML

```
    ...
    <br><button ng-click="loadL(teacher.name)">{{teacher.name}}</button>
    ...
    <div ng-repeat="teacher in teachers | filter:{name:searchname}">                        
    ...
```

В JS изменится только *loadL()* в ней просто записывается имя учителя в searchname для последующей фильтрации

```
     $scope.searchname=''
     $scope.loadL = function (name){
                    $scope.searchname=name
     };
```